# Abrupt scrolling with NestedScrollView in ViewPager Fragment inside a CoordinatorLayout Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I am facing a major scrolling problem with `ViewPager` inside `CoordinatorLayout`.

**The current scene:**

1. `app:appbarScrollingViewBehaviour` is set on `ViewPager`.
2. The `ViewPager` fragment has `NestedScrollView` as its root parent.
3. The fragment layout contains Horizontal `RecyclerView`.
4. When I scroll up by touching over `RecyclerView`, the app bar doesn't scroll, instead only nested scrolling occurs.
5. When I scroll by touching rest of the view, the `CoordinatorLayout` scrolls.
   6) Also the nested scrolling stops midway and cuts off the content.

**What I have tried already:**

1. Putting `ViewPager` inside `NestedScrollView` and set  `app:appbarScrollingViewBehaviour` attribute to `NestedScrollView`. This completely cuts off the fragment content as `RecyclerView` cannot decide its height.
2. Setting `setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)` on `RecyclerView`, still not able to fix height.
3. And many other approaches.
   Please help with this issue. The current behavior can be seen in uploaded *.gif*. I am also posting my code for Activity layout and fragment layout and `RecyclerView` row layout.

Thank you

**activity.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:Customs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/new_color_primary_skim">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />



   <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Workout"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="19sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />
            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/workout_insights_graph"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true" />

            <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.SlidingTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/diet_insights_graph"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/transparent" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top"
            android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/workout_translucent" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**pager_fragment.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:Customs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:paddingRight="7dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/round_gray_dark"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


   <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Target Calories to burn : "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />



<com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="2300"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">



 <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Burned calories : "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />


   <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="2300"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


    <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Total workout time : "
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />



   <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="20 mins"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/round_gray_dark"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/textView27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Today"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/round_gray_dark"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


            <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tomorrow"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:alpha="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/round_gray_dark"
                android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


       <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Target Calories to burn : "
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />


      <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2300"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


      <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Total workout time : "
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />


      <com.fitsquare.app.fitsquare.Entity.Customs.CustomFontTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="20 mins"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        Customs:font="LatoRegular.ttf" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

  <!--  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@color/transparent" />-->
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: So can you explain you problem in detail? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution and solved the problem myself. As the horizontal RecyclerView was a child of Nested Scroll View, it wasn't transferring scroll events to CoordinatorLayout. I just solved it by disabling nested scrolling using this line of code.
`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`